# SVG inline in CSS not working in FireFox

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to inline a svg in my css

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml ......');
```

Here is an example with my original SVG, which does work in Chrome but not in FireFox: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfrrf/35/)

To understand the problem I created this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6WAtQ/757/). I've used different SVGs and they work, except the one attached to the `#a0` element (this one also doesn't work in Chrome)

Does someone know why FF doesn't render the SVG ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data URI is invalid as it contains # characters which are reserved to indicate the start of [a fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

You need to [URL encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the data in order for it to be valid and for Firefox to display it. URL encoding will replace the # character by %23, it may replace other reserved characters depending on which, if any you've used.

Comment: thanks a lot, I now use `rgb` and it works like a charm!